# Unable to replace alias "mea.twig.JsExtension" , Symfony 3.4 service alias

Tags: symfony, symfony-3.4

services.yml

```
mea.twig.JsExtension:
    alias: Mea\CoreBundle\Twig\MeaExtension
    public: true
    arguments: ["@service_container","@kernel", "@mea.metatags", "@mea.asset"]
    tags:
        - { name: twig.extension }
```

give error

```
InvalidArgumentException
Unable to replace alias "mea.twig.JsExtension" with actual definition "Mea\CoreBundle\Twig\MeaExtension".

in ReplaceAliasByActualDefinitionPass.php (line 57)
at ReplaceAliasByActualDefinitionPass->process(object(ContainerBuilder))
in Compiler.php (line 141)
at Compiler->compile(object(ContainerBuilder))
in ContainerBuilder.php (line 759)
at ContainerBuilder->compile()
in Kernel.php (line 643)
```

Symfony 3.4

Answer (score 0):

There are 4 possible causes of it and they might be perfectly undersended by exceptions of `Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\InvalidArgumentException` type:

- `ServiceNotFoundException`;
- `ParameterNotFoundException`;
- `EnvNotFoundException`;
- `EnvParameterException`.

I'm sure first exception is the the real cause of your problem.